# Search in Applications Help menu

Tags: plugins, macosx

In OSX (also know as macOS) there is a very handy feature:
In the sub menu of the help menu there is a search function which search in other sub menus of the application. Is there something like that for Unity or Linux?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is the [**Unity HUD (Head-Up Display)**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/HUD).

It is a little search box that appears in the top left corner of your screen when you briefly tap the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

You may enter a query there and the HUD will search your currently focused window's menus for it.

The search result list can be navigated using the <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd> or the mouse. The effect is the same as if you navigated the application's menu to click the selected item.

[image: Unity HUD screenshot]